# How do I safely release an object shared between threads using boost::shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, thread-safety, shared-ptr

I wonder, is it safe to implement like this? :

```
typedef shared_ptr<Foo>  FooPtr;    
FooPtr                  *gPtrToFooPtr    // global variable

// init (before any thread has been created)
void init()
{
    gPtrToFooPtr = new FooPtr(new Foo);
}

// thread A, B, C, ..., K
// Once thread Z execute read_and_drop(), 
// no more call to read() from any thread.
// But it is possible even after read_and_drop() has returned,
// some thread is still in read() function.
void read()
{
    FooPtr a = *gPtrToFooPtr;
    // do useful things (read only)
}

// thread Z (executed once)
void read_and_drop()
{
    FooPtr b = *gPtrToFooPtr;
    // do useful things with a (read only)
    b.reset();
}
```

We do not know which thread would do the actual realease.
Does boost's `shared_ptr` do the release safely under circumstance like this?

According to boost's document, thread safety of `shared_ptr` is:

> A `shared_ptr` instance can be "read" (accessed using only const
>   operations) simultaneously by multiple threads. ***Different*** `shared_ptr`
>   instances can be "written to" (accessed using mutable operations such
>   as operator`=` or `reset`) simultaneosly by multiple threads.

As far as I am concerned, the code above does not violate any of thread safety criteria I mentioned above. And I believe the code should run fine. Does anyone tell me if I am right or wrong?

Thanks in advance.

---

### **Editted 2012-06-20 01:00 UTC+9**

The pseudo code above works fine. The `shared_ptr` implementation guarantees to work correctly under circumstances where multiple thread is accessing instances of it (each thread **MUST** access its own instance of `shared_ptr` instantiated by using *copy constructor*).

Note that in the pseudo code above, you must `delete gPtrToFooPtr` to have the `shared_ptr` implementation finally release (drop the reference count by one) the object it owns(not proper expression since it is not an `auto_ptr`, but who cares ;) ). And in this case, you must be aware of the fact that it may cause SIGSEGV in multithreaded application.

Answer (score 1):

How do you define 'safe' here? If you define it as 'I want to make sure that the object is destroyed exactly once', then YES, the release is safe. However, the problem is that the two threads share one smart pointer in your example. This is not safe at all. The `reset()` performed by one thread might not be visible to the other thread.

As stated by the documentation, smart pointers offer the same guarantees as built in types (i.e., pointers). Therefore, it is problematic to perform an unguarded write while an other thread might still be reading. It is undefined when that other reading thread will see writes of the other one. Therefore, while one thread calls `reset()` the pointer might NOT be reset in the other thread, since the shared_ptr instance itself is shared.

If you want some sort of thread safety, you have to use two shared pointer instances. Then, of course, resetting one of them WILL NOT release the object, since the other thread still has a reference to it. Usually this behaviour is intended.

However, I think the bigger problem is that you are misusing shared_ptrs. It is quite uncommon to use pointers of shared_ptrs and to allocate the shared_ptr on the heap (using new). If you do that, you have the problem you wanted to avoid using smart pointers again (you have to manage the lifetime of the shared_ptr now). Maybe check out some example code about smart pointers and their usage first.

Comment: Then, how about changing the type of global shared_ptr to, say, `FooPtr gFooPtr;` and, assignments to `FooPtr a = gFooPtr;` and `FooPtr b = gFooPtr;`? I guess it is same as using a pointer to dynamically allocated shared_ptr instance.

Comment: And I think that the 'unguarded write' will be prevented by reference count of shared_ptr that is protected by lock-free mechanism provided by boost. Because the only possible write happens when the instance of Foo is released, and it is protected by reference count of shared_ptr.

Comment: that would be better (see also the edits in my post, better read it again). But then, there are TWO references to the object, therefore, resetting only one of them will NOT release the object. You have to reset the pointer in each thread. This is usually the intended behaviour of a smart pointer: If one thread still has a valid handle, it MAY NOT be the case that another thread is able to delete the object. Therefore, the best idea would be to give each thread an own smart pointer instance and reset it when the thread is done.

Comment: @Your second comment: Yes, the reference count is protected! But that is the only thing that is protected. What is NOT protected are the pointers themselves. I.e., if you have a smart pointer instance that is shared by two threads (always not a good idea), then resetting the pointer WILL destroy the object (correct behaviour) but the other thread might not see that the pointer was reset (incorrect behaviour). So again: The release itself is fine. The object is destroyed. But another thread might have a shared pointer which still points to the destroyed object.

Comment: Well, @orchistro is using multiple instances of `shared_ptr` since `FooPtr b = *gPtrToFooPtr;` *copy-constructs* a new `shared_ptr` on the stack of thread Z. Calling `reset()` on this `shared_ptr` is safe since the ref count is protected.

Comment: oh, yes, misread that. But then, releasing it in only one thread will still not do what he wants. He must reset each pointer in each thread to deallocate the object.

Comment: @JohannesS., Yes, you understand my intent correctly. While instantiating `sharet_ptr` in heap using `new` is not a common practice, it was neccessary in what I attempted to achive (my explanation was somewhat unsufficient in that respect).

Comment: @gexicide, **First of all**, thanks interest you've shown to my question. I actually wrote some code today to test the issue: whether 'the object is destroyed exactly once' (as you wrote in your answer). It worked perfectly fine with multiple threads simultaneasouly reading `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @gexicide, **Second of all**, every instance of `shared_ptr` instantiated by using _copy constructor_ **shares refrence count** of the original one. If you `reset()` one of copied instance of `shared_ptr`, then every reference count, including the one in the original one, will drop by one. And as boost documentation says, _Different shared_ptr instances can be "written to" (accessed using mutable operations such as operator= or reset) *simultaneosly by multiple threads*_ (If this type of thread safety were not guaranteed, what are the meaning of the existence of `shared_ptr`!)

Comment: @gexicide, **Finally**, I was successful in implementaning what I originally had in mind, though I needed some kind of [shared-exclusive lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock) to protect the glabal `shared_ptr` instance to keep the `Foo` object alive in memory.

Comment: @gexicide, After all, it turned out that your comment that I would be better off not using dynamically allocated `shared_ptr` instance was truthful. After I had decided to finally use some form or locking mechanism, I did not need the 'wierd' `shared_ptr` (I needed it to avoid using locking mechanism, just changing pointer variable to use another `shared_ptr` instance.)

@gexicide, @JohannesS. Thank you all :-)

Comment: One more thing about `shared_ptr::reset()`: it acts like the underlying concept of `reset()` is 'abandoning the ownership of the object that the `shared_ptr` instance have'. If you call the method twice on the same instance of `shared_ptr`, the first call drops the reference count, and the second call doesn't.

Comment: "_It is undefined when_" Not "when"; it's UB, period.

Comment: "_I did not need the 'wierd' shared_ptr (I needed it to avoid using locking mechanism, just changing pointer variable to use another shared_ptr instance.)_" NO! This absurd construct is not needed and cannot help. Please learn MT programming, do not try to make up stuff based on your intuition.

Comment: @JohannesS. "_Calling reset() on this shared_ptr is safe since the ref count is protected._" And it's useless. The object is to be destroyed immediately after.

Answer (score 1):

For your own good, I will be honest.

Your code is doing many things and almost all are simply useless and absurd.

```
typedef shared_ptr<Foo>  FooPtr;    
FooPtr                  *gPtrToFooPtr    // global variable
```

A raw pointer to a smart pointer, cancels the advantage of automatic resource management and does not solve any problem.

```
void read()
{
    FooPtr a = *gPtrToFooPtr;
    // do useful things (read only)
}
```

`a` is not used in any meaningful way.

```
{
    FooPtr b = ...
    b.reset();
}
```

`b.reset()` is useless here, `b` is about to be destroyed anyway. `b` has no purpose in this function.

I am afraid you have no idea what you are doing, what smart pointers are for, how to use `shared_ptr`, and how to do MT programming; so, you end up with this absurd pile of useless features to not solve the problem.

What about **doing simple things simply**:

```
Foo f;

// called before others functions 
void init() {
    // prepare f
}

// called in many threads {R1, R2, ... Rn} in parallel
void read()
{
    // use f (read-only)
}

// called after all threads {R1, R2, ... Rn} have terminated
void read_and_drop()
{
    // reset f
}
```

`read_and_drop()` **must not be called before** it can be guaranteed that other threads are not reading `f`.

Comment: First of all, I appreciate your candor, thanks. Secondly, I have realized that my idea was totally wrong, and I have done it my way a few hours after I had written this post, and it looks a lot like what you had to suggest. Lastly, your tone hurts $'(

Comment: I am sorry about that last part. Inter-thread communication must be done with a proper synchronisation primitive (mutex, mutex+condition, barrier...) not a raw pointer, a `shared_ptr`, or a combination of both. The other answers failed to make these essential points, and that is why I felt the need to post this answer.

Answer (score -1):

To your edit:

Why not call `reset()` first on the global `shared_ptr`?

- If you were the last one to access the object, fine it is deleted, then you delete the `shared_ptr` on the heap.
- If some other thread still uses it, you reduce the ref count by one, and "disconnect" the global ptr from the (still existing) object that is pointed-to. You can then safely delete the `shared_ptr` on the heap without affecting any thread that might still use it.

Comment: I needed to keep at least one instance of the object.

Comment: I was only to referring to your comment that people who delete the global pointer need be careful to avoid a SIGSEGV. This should be avoided by my approach.

Comment: Oh, yes, decreasing reference counter by calling `reset()` would guarantee releasing of the object owned by the shared_ptr instance.
When I mentioned SIGSEGV, I had my pseudo code in mind, where the global instance of shared_ptr resides not in stack, but in heap. At the end of the day, you will need to release the memory area used to hold the global shared_ptr some time. When you `free()` it, I meant, be careful to make sure no other thread will try to copy the global shared_ptr. Anyway, due to lack of my explanation about the requirements I am facing, some things may seem a little bit odd.

Comment: "_Why not call reset() first on the global shared_ptr?_" No. `read()` can still be executing when `reset()` is called.